# Power BI Reporting Solution design

Tags: azure, security, model, powerbi

Up until now I've only ever created SQL databases / Views etc that you connect to in Power BI and create your own simple reports. I've populated data using Azure Data factory and or SSIS.

I think the below solution is a little more complex so the model when imported has all the joins already configured and the tables and field names are are clear and obvious to the Report developers.

My questions / assumptions are in brackets ()

Present design that full fills the below requirements.

Project: Create reports using Power BI

Source is single Azure SQL DB (very small sales data about 15 tables or less).

Design:-

Design a solution using **Microsoft Azure to ETL/ELT, stage, model**. (What is this exactly? Are they referring to "tabular data models" ?)

Output:-

Provide solution using above as in input to Power BI so users can create their own reports. (What data source is the input?)

Data is Sales related so need to be able to restrict users to their own sales region data.

Senior management though can see everything.

What's the best way to apply security to to Azure Data?

Up until now I've only ever created SQL databases / Views etc that you connect to in Power BI and create your own simple reports. I've populated data using Azure Data factory and or SSIS.

I've developed Python code to import Firebase data, Excel data imported through Data Factor.

In the Azure SQL I've created views that join the data together and summarise it.

Users would use Power BI desktop to connect to the SQL Database and create their own reports.

My objective I believe is a little more advanced than I've done up until now.

Any help / advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Source is single Azure SQL DB (very small sales data about 15 tables or less).

There's no need to "Design a solution using Microsoft Azure to ETL/ELT, stage, model." here.

The next step in maturity is to create a shared dataset for the report writers to connect to, so they don't have to connect directly to your Azure SQL Database.

Just import that data into a Power BI Dataset, with using table and column names that are meaningful to the users writing reports, all the appropriate relationships in place, ideally with a [star schema data model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/star-schema), and important business metrics pre-defined as [measures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-measures).

Share the Dataset with your report writers and they will see it in their Power BI Data Hub when writing new reports.

Comment: Many thanks David for your reply.  Unfortunately for me this is the task I've been set for a job interview presentation. I agree with you but I have to present using their desired solution.  Next comment is their requirement.

Comment: "A customer has asked for the ability to create PowerBI reports with their data. The source system is a single Azure SQL DB with 10 tables with a total size of less than 1Gb. You are required to design a solution using Microsoft Azure to ETL/ELT, stage, model and present the data to PowerBI to allow the customer to make their own reports. Security considerations need to be taken into account so managers from each region can only see their data with Senior directors able to see everything. Your presentation will need to cover why you have chosen certain components."

Comment: That's not really SO can help with.  You'll need to research Azure and come up with a solution architecture.  EG https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/solution-ideas/articles/big-data-analytics-enterprise-grade-security  The next generation of these analytics services is a unified solution called Microsoft Fabric, so you can research that too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/get-started/microsoft-fabric-overview